# Helper Text is not showing my Error and my Error Message is not appearring if my Login Data is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I am trying to show my wrong errors within my helper text component ( I am using Materal UI).

I can see all my Errors by Testing my Backend End code perfectly ( I am using Postman to make the test)
Morover I can not see my ErrorMessage under the button, which should appear, when my Login Data is invalid

I am able to make a successfull login after all (If the credentials are all right)

Thats my code

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react'
        import axios from 'axios'
        import { Button, Grid, TextField, Typography, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core'
        import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
    
    const styles = {
        form: {
            textAlign: 'center'
        },
        pageTitle: {
            margin: '20px auto 20px auto'
        },
        textField: {
            margin: '10px auto 10px auto'
        },
        button: {
            marginTop: 20
        },
        customError: {
            color: 'red',
            fontsize: '0.8rem'
        }
    
    }
    
    
    class login extends Component {
    
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                email: '',
                password: '',
                errors: {}
            };
        }
    
        handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('h1')
            const userData = {
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password
            };
    
            axios
                .post('/login', userData)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data)
                    this.setState({
                        loading: false
                    })
                    this.props.history.push('/')
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    this.setState({
                        errors: err.response.data,
                        loading: false
                    })
                })
    
        }
    
    
        handleChange = (event) => {
            this.setState({
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value
            });
        }
    
    
        render() {
    
            const { classes } = this.props
            const { errors } = this.state
    
            return (
                <Grid container className={classes.form}>
                    <Grid item sm />
                    <Grid item sm>
                        <Typography variant="h2" className={classes.pageTitle}>
                            Login
              </Typography>
                        <form noValidate onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <TextField
                                id="email"
                                name="email"
                                type="email"
                                label="Email"
                                className={classes.textField}
                                helperText={errors.email} // Thats not workig
                                error={errors.email ? true : false}
                                value={this.state.email}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                fullWidth
                            />
                            <TextField
                                id="password"
                                name="password"
                                type="password"
                                label="Password"
                                className={classes.textField}
                                helperText={errors.password}
                 

           error={errors.password ? true : false}
                            value={this.state.password}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            fullWidth  
                        />

/>
                    {errors.general && (
                        <Typography variant="body2" className={classes.customError}>
                            {errors.general}  
                        </Typography>  // Thats not workig
                    )}
                    <Button
             

           type="submit"
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            className={classes.button}

                        >
                            Login
                        </Button>
                    </form>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm />
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

login.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default withStyles(styles)(login);
```

p.s thats my validator function, which is showing the error

```
      exports.validateLoginData = (data) => {


  let errors = {};

    if (isEmpty(data.email)) errors.email = 'Must not be empty';
    if (isEmpty(data.password)) errors.password = 'Must not be empty';

    return {

        errors,
        valid: Object.keys(errors).length === 0 ? true : false
    };
};
```

and part of the login route

```
.catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            // auth/wrong-password
            // auth/user-not-user
            return res
                .status(403)
                .json({ general: "Wrong credentials, please try again" });
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to console.log this : `err.response.data` in catch callback from axios post you can see an object `{ errors: {}, valid: false }` (as a deduction on your backend code)

You have to bind `errors` like this :

```
.catch((err) => {
    this.setState({
        errors: err.response.data.errors,
        loading: false
    })
})
```

Comment: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined ( my New error)  It appears here  94 | helperText={errors.email}